# "use strict" only in debug?

Tags: javascript, minify, use-strict

I wonder if there is really nessesary to include the `"use strict"` when I am done programming and release my JavaScript document to anyone to see. I like to use it because to check that I have coded in a good way.

So, should I include or just remove use `"use strict"` when I release my JavaScript file for the public?

The reason why I ask is to save space in my JavaScript file.

Comment: "*save space in my JavaScript file*" - seriously, how big are your JavaScript files (even after compression?)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz It must be just about full :P

Comment: If your bandwidth bill is so high that the 10 bytes of `use strict` break the bank, you might want to switch ISPs...

Comment: 7 kb is the one that I am working on right now. Someone told me that if I exeeded 10 kb it would make my web page load really slow. Slow is 1 second.

Comment: @user1431627 A 10kb Javscript file is probably the least of your worries. That's not very much data to transfer. If you have images on your site you can probably save a whole lot more bandwidth by optimizing them. You can minify the whole file using a Javascript minifier though and I'm sure you'll save more than what you save by removing `"use strict";`.

Comment: @user1431627. Don't ever listen to that "someone" again. EVER!

Comment: @gdoron Minifying `"use strict";`is one of many things I am trying to help bring down the file size, so I will never remove it. And that someone is a specialist is science and have been programming in C++ witch is, in turn, JavaScript.

Comment: @user1431627. If you have the smallest image in the website, it will be a lot more then 10K, I'm telling you, the guy doesn't know what he's talking about. You don't have to believe me, read all other comments and answers...

Comment: My web page only contains a 4 kb web page and the JavaScript file. No images - the future of web development! I have the fastest site alive!

Comment: *"C++ witch is, in turn, JavaScript"* I'd be interested to know about this connection between C++ and JavaScript, and how it relates to website performance.

Comment: @amnotiam They looks very alike. Isn't there a production of C++ for HTML? :)

Comment: @amnotiam. I would love to hear your opinion about `"use strict"` in production. What do you think? You can write a comment or edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user1431627. you realise that `"use strict";` is 0.3% of the size of your 4kB web page, right? Also, C++ and Javascript are **fundamentally** different. C++ is class-based; Javascript is prototype-based. C++ is strongly type; Javascript is weakly typed. C++ is compiled; Javascript is interpreted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found two opinions about using `strict mode` in production:

> There is no reason to ship “use strict” in your production code. There is no performance gain (verified with V8 team and Brendan a while ago) and I don’t need my users’ VMs doing the extra checks as well. Keep it development only, strip it out during build. This way you also avoid the concatenation issue you reference.

And:

> There may not be a performance gain, but there’s also not a performance loss. In production, even more than in development, is where you want to be sure you’re noticing errors. Minimizing the changes between the development and production versions of the code is key to being able to debug issues quickly and efficiently. Yes it helps during development, but there’s no reason to pull it out of production code.

[The source is in the comments at the bottom](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/)

And of course those `12b` weight of `"use strict"` won't change a thing.

Comment: Interesting quotes. Regarding the question, this seems like OP has already decided that the 12 bytes saved are worthwhile. I find it hard to believe, especially if it needs to be removed manually as opposed to being part of a build process. There are some strict mode changes that aren't backward compatible, so removing the declarative could break code in those situations. But if non-strict implementations are being supported, those changes are likely (hopefully) not being used in a non-compatible way.

Comment: @amnotiam. Which strict-mode features aren't supported in the non strict-mode? Or I completely lost you there...? Do you use `strict-mode`?

Comment: Yes I do use strict, but I've been doing more server side lately, so no compatibility issue. There are probably several, but the first that come to mind is the calling context of functions. In strict mode, it can be any value, including primitives, even `null` or `undefined`, whereas in non-strict, you're guaranteed that it will always be an object, and the default is `undefined`. Another change is the `arguments` object mapping to formal parameters. In strict, they are entirely separate values. Changing a parameter doesn't affect the `arguments` object and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The line `"use strict";` makes up 13 bytes of your file. I'd suggest that this is unlikely to even approach 1% of your file size.

Use one of the many minifiers out there to reduce your file size, along with gzip comression on the server-side, if you're concerned about bandwidth. Manually removing 13 bytes is a false economy.

Exactly which minifier may depend on your code, but [here are some suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=js%20minifier#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=js%20minify&oq=js%20minify&aq=f&aqi=g2g-s1g1&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i10j0.6701.7769.0.7897.4.4.0.0.0.0.121.468.0j4.4.0.eish.1.0.0.iZtCK6Tjbjg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1c83fcc631ee06da&biw=1920&bih=947).

Answer (score 2):

Certainly its a micro-optimization, but if you're concatenating (say 25) JS modules together, thats all of the sudden 250bytes.

Deploying to production in a high traffic application,  with say 1000 hits per minute, thats 130+ Gb a year of traffic you can prevent if your build removed the `'use strict';`s

I'm sure that would save a few bucks on AWS...

I haven't seen a compelling argument to keep it in production other than its not worth the time. It probably isn't, but if you already have a build system, and the know-how to pull this off with minimal effort, why not?

Comment: It will be a lot less than 250 bytes because of gzip

Comment: i wonder if there's any reason why the many JS minimizers out there don't (offer the option to) strip this out?

Comment: This is a pretty fallacious argument. Assuming the network bandwidth was $1/GB (extremely high), it's not like the owner of any website serving __half a billion requests per year__ would worry about $130/year.

Comment: @abhidivekar A "half a billion requests per year" isn't even that high. Google literally does trillions. And if a tool like uglifyJS could do this, and even decrease bundle sizes by a few bites, I don't see what that would be a bad thing. And I'll say it again, yes, it would be a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I would currently recommend that you remove the "use strict" in any code that is intended for production (and just use it in debug).

However, I wouldn't remove it just to make the file(s) smaller. The reason I would remove it is because it currently appears to have a negative impact on the actual performance of JavaScript when executed. Hopefully this will change eventually, but for now I would omit it for performance reasons.